# How to get version of magento 2

Tags: magento2, version

In Magento 1, you can use `Mage::getVersion()`. But I can't find code for getting version in Magento 2.

Comment: try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mage2x-magento-2-version/ikmndhpkjkjmhhoackhijohlplkimpdk

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**[1]** Via Code

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
   $version = $productMetadata->getVersion(); //will return the magento version
```

**[2]** Go to CLI, Locate your Magento Root Folder & Run below command

```
php bin/magento --version
```

**Output**

> Magento CLI version 2.1.1

Which print your Current Magento Version

**[3]** If you open `composer.json` on Magento Root You can find as well

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.1",
```

**[4]** From Admin Side, On Right Hand Side Footer Also You can see

Comment: For the third method, it is unlikely to happen, but if you executed the comand `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update` (recommended way to upgrade) but did not execute `composer update` after, you will see the version as `2.1.8`, but your Magento won't be at that version yet.

Answer (score 8):

On top of the other answer, you can get the major version (for example 2.1) by **accessing `/magento_version` on your Magento 2 website.**

Comment: And please, disable this feature as soon as you can.. bin/magento module:disable Magento_Version